Modify composite key with EF
I have these 3 tables:

I'm trying update column id_rol on table Users_Roles trought EF:
var ur = db1.CRM_Users_Roles_N01
    .Where(x => x.id_user == cRM_Users_Roles_N01.id_user).SingleOrDefault();
ur.id_rol = cRM_Users_Roles_N01.id_rol;
db1.Entry(cRM_Users_N01).State = EntityState.Modified

but VS throwing follow exception:
Property 'id_rol' is part of the information object key, it can't modify.
How can I modify column id_rol in Users_Roles table with EF and without modify the actual database structure?.
Thanks in advance.

Does this answer your question? The property is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified and I NEEDto modify it

Nope, in my case really are a composite key in the Users_Roles table and that's rigth but i need update the column id_rol

ur.id_rol = cRM_Users_Roles_N01.id_rol; I'm not sure I understand this line. What is cRM_Users_Roles_N01 in this statement.

In any event, it should certainly work to delete the old key and add a new one, as suggested in the first comments link. It does appear to be a type of chicken egg question - how do you track objects when you are changing the information used to track the objects? EF Core is not by any means a perfect way to work with data so you may have to accept its limitations. I suppose another alternative (not available to you perhaps) is to add an arbitrary primary key to the middle table, and then make the two current primary key columns simply two fields with a unique index on them.

Thanks a lot guys, just how @topsail says I had to remove an then insert the new data.

That's also what was suggested in the answer of my suggested duplicate link (option 2).

Yes, thanl you so much.
